# Select val and text from all dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to select the val and text from all dropdowns on the page:
Here is the code that gives me all `vals`

```
var selected = $('select[name^=dropdown_').map(function () {
  if ($(this).val())
    return $(this).val();
}).get();
```

how can I get the selected text as well? So in result I would get an array of pair `object.val` and `object.text`;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a blank array and Store all values and selected text in object:

```
var _select = [];

$('select[name^=dropdown_').each( function () {
    var _obj = {};
    _obj.val = $(this).val();
    _obj.text = $('option:selected', this).text();
    _select.push(_obj);
});
console.log(_select);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/j1qsym0s/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = [];
$("select").each(function(){  
  var text = this.value;    
  var id = $( this ).attr( "id" );   
  result.push({text, id });
});

console.info( result );
```

Comment: There is no ID on the options. See other answer